# Using react in a legacy jquery + java spring project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

**Backstory:** My boss has given me the mission to figure out how to implement react into one of our existing codebases. The idea is to use this to test integration and see if we can slowly migrate out projects over to react. As well to demonstrate to those in charge improvement react can offer over jquery.  The problem is I only have less than 2 years of web experience most of which is jquery and near zero of that is react. So I'm struggling to learn the process of integrating react. This is made more challenging by figuring out supporting systems like webpack, npm, and varies libs used with react.

**Goal-1:** Get a single page running react inside an existing layout that can support modules/libs

**Goal-2:** Get this page to play well with our jquery menu (option as I can rewrite it)

**Goal-3:** Get everything placed into its respective folders inside our src/main/webapp

**Current state:** I have a page loading react and babel using simple script tags. This works but is rather difficult getting any other react libs to load. As most assume npm is being used or commonjs at the minimal. Neither of these I have much knowledge with using/implementing.

**What I need:** *Some guidance* on how to implement react into an existing project. I've run over a few articles talking about the process but many lack details needed to understand what is going on in each step. For example getting webpack to export into the target directory so it can be bundled for use in tomcat.

Comment: since this is on hold feel free to lock or delete it. I can't easily reword the question since it was directed at getting guidance/resources/insight rather than a solution. This way I could better word questions into specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this ends up closed, my high level thoughts is get your spring project into a state where it is exposing RESTful endpoints for getting and saving your data.  Then build the react project separately from the current java or jquery projects, and have the react ui consume those REST apis.

Apart from that, this is a very broad question you are asking, with lots of ways to solve it, the above mentioned is only a starting point.  I couldnt possibly go into complete architecture here..

Comment: Hence why I'm asking for guidance rather than a solution in itself. Your advice is solid but my boss has already rejected that idea. As we lack the QA resources to retest an entire application and also lack the resources to rewrite the entire app at this time. Its why we are aiming for a slow approach so we can start introducing new technology while removing the old over time. Effectively it might only be me doing this work with the oversight of my boss and 1 QA guy. While the rest of our team focuses on other tasks.

Comment: You need a more realistic boss then...

Comment: True, honestly he might be more open to the idea later. I think he wants to see if its possible before going to the next option. Though at least I can say he is open to the idea of new tech considering he has worked here 15+ years. He is also making a strong push to get us updated to a more stream lined system using git, java 8+, docker, etc.

Comment: Had a chat with my boss again about this, turns out I was right he is open to the idea. If we do a future app we are going to do two workspaces. The first for our front end only containing react and a second for our backend doing only the rest side of things. Going to mark your answer as the correct one since this is our end goal now.